# Save and return randomly generated strings in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, sessionstorage

Okay so basically what I'm trying to do is to display all the randomly generated strings on the page, after being saved in sessionStorage. So far, my createRandom function works fine on its own, but when I added the returnRandom function both stopped working. I appreciate any suggestions.

Here is the javascript:

```
function createRandom()
{
    var text = "";
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += alphabet.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length));

    document.getElementById("randomstring").innerHTML= text;
    sessionStorage.setItem(text, text);
    returnRandom();
}
document.getElementById("button").addEventListener("click", createRandom, false);


    // //returns session storage values
function returnRandom() {
    var key =  "";
    var i = 0;
    for (var i = 0, i <= sessionStorage.length - 1, i++) {
        key = sessionStorage.key(i);
        var item = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
        document.getElementById("randomreturn").innerHTML += item;
    }
}
```

And here is the html:

```
<h2 id="randomstring">Random</h2>
<div id="button">
    <p class="buttontext">Click Me</p>
</div>
<h3 id="randomreturn"></h3>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop expression should have semicolons, not commas

```
    for (var i = 0; i <= sessionStorage.length - 1; i++)
```

Comment: Stupid mistake, thanks for catching it, although the function still doesn't work... @pll33